# How to fix Android calling problem in dual sim mobiles?

Tags: java, android, call

Can't select sim while calling from my android app.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyIeA.jpg)
The sim 1 and sim 2 are disabled, can't select from dialog box. Please check the image attached.
Here is my code;

```
                Intent callintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                String strMobNo = callDialogNumber.getText().toString().trim();
                callintent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + strMobNo));
                startActivity(callintent);
```

the error mainly occurring on android version 12.